# Problems making xrdp work on Stretch

Tags: xrdp

I have purged realvnc-vnc-server.
I have loaded xrdp
At this point nothing appear but instructions say that the xrdp server is supposed to run automatically in the background.
How do I access it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the command:

```
 sudo startx
```

This should start the xrdp server desktop and then you can connect to it.

Comment: **DO NOT** use `sudo startx` a simple `startx` starts the user desktop.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I found an old YouTube video that had me uninstall xrdp along with vnc and tightvncserver. Basically start clean. I did so and then reloaded 1st tightvncserver and then xrdp and it worked. Now all I have to do is to figure how I get sound playing from the Pi to my W10 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

`xrdp` is a server, it is not supposed to display anything. You need to connect to it (from another computer) using an RDP client such as [`rdesktop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rdesktop) or [`freerdp`](https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/User/FreeRDP-User-Manual.markdown).